# Laptop falls-back to Vesa video-driver

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, drivers, video, laptop

I own Dell Inspiron 15R SE (7520) and I have installed Arch Linux on it. It seems that I have two video-cards so I have installed both drivers + Vesa driver (pardon me if that's wrong).

```
dagrevis@haze ~ » lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cape Verde [Radeon HD 7700M Series]
dagrevis@haze ~ » pacman -Ss xf86-video | grep installed
extra/xf86-video-ati 1:7.0.0-1 (xorg-drivers xorg) [installed]
extra/xf86-video-intel 2.20.13-1 (xorg-drivers xorg) [installed]
extra/xf86-video-vesa 2.3.2-2 (xorg-drivers xorg) [installed]
```

When I execute `startx`, it loads-up, but, sadly, using Vesa. Here's [Xorg.0.log](http://sprunge.us/ZUEc).

Why's that? How can I fix it? Thanks!

P.S. I would be happy to use just Intel card and don't touch ATI at all.

Answer (score 1):

After done some deeper reading in log file, I executed:`sudo pacman -S xf86-video-modesetting xf86-video-fbdev` and installed packages that were missing. Then, I removed Vesa and ATI driver: `sudo pacman -R xf86-video-vesa xf86-video-ati` and that seemed to did the trick — I'm using Intel drivers. :)